# moving an image with multiple instances of jquery animate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have an image that I need to move across the page back and forth and up and down at the same time. I can't get them all to run at once together, individually they work fine. I m wondering how I can combine the functions to get them to run all at once.

```
   var homeWide = $('.container').width(); 
   var width = (homeWide - "250");

   moveRight = function() {
        $('img.homeFish').stop(true,true).animate({left: width}, 5000, 
         moveLeft);
   };

      moveLeft = function() {
        $('img.homeFish').stop(true,true).animate({left: 0}, 5000, moveRight);
   };

   moveRight();


  function loop() {
    $('img.homeFish').animate({'top': '10'}, {
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function() {
            $('img.homeFish').animate({top: 0}, {
                duration: 1000, 
                complete: loop});
    }});

}
loop();
```

Comment: It would help if we could see a working example of this in a snippet, or at least the associated HTML and CSS. That aside, I'd suggest doing this using CSS as it will perform much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A css only animation, if this *is* what you want:

```css
#img{
  animation: wave 5s linear alternate infinite;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes wave{
  0%{ transform: translate(0vw, 0vh);}
  20%{ transform: translate(20vw, 100vh);}
  40%{ transform: translate(40vw, 0vh);}
  60%{ transform: translate(60vw, 100vh);}
  80%{ transform: translate(80vw, 0vh);}
  100%{ transform: translate(100vw, 100vh);}
}


.as-console-wrapper{display: none !important;}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohit that worked perfectly, I just changed to translate values to what I needed. I wasn't sure if css or jquery was better but this works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
  function loop() {
    $('img.homeFish').animate({'top': '10'}, {
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function() {
            $('img.homeFish').animate({top: 0}, {
                duration: 1000, 
                complete: function() {loop();}
            });
    }});
  }
```